# How can you bypass Tesseract OCR's internal image pre-processing?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

In many cases, Tesseract OCR's internal image pre-processing is degrading the quality of the image. I want to control the image processing before feeding to Tesseract OCR and disable the OCR's internal pre-processing steps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean with "degrading the quality of the image", but tesseract use binarized image for OCR, so if you provide binarized image as input, you can skip tesseract internal function for this. AFAIK there is no other preprocessing in tesseract (user has to do preprocessing).